# page getting refresh after using update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using `Ajax Rating Control` inside my `datalist`. i used this rating control inside the update panel, so that when user give rate , page wouldn't get refreshed. but still page is getting Refreshed. 
here is my complete code .

```
<div class="rating">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPanelRating" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                  <asp:Rating ID="ratPro" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" StarCssClass="Star" OnChanged="ratPro_Changed"
                        WaitingStarCssClass="WaitingStar" EmptyStarCssClass="Star" FilledStarCssClass="FilledStar">
                   </asp:Rating>
              </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

what should i do now , so that page don't get refreshed, and user's given star store in database. i just want to stop the page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `AutoPostBack="true"` attribute in the `asp:Rating` control. This triggers an automatic postback, or a refresh, as it is seen by the user.

Alternatively, maybe you should try `ajaxToolkit:Rating` instead of `asp:Rating`

Comment: but i have used this control inside the update panel, so it should not refresh the whole page ,

Comment: did you try removing the attribute ?